# Help ! bizzare integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How to integrate $$ I_1=\underbrace{\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}}dx}_{I_1} $$ and $$I_2=\underbrace{\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}}}_{I_2}$$

Comment: How are indefinite integrals like this related to complex analysis?

Comment: Are you sure it's $\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}$ and not $\sqrt{9x^4+6x^2+1}$?

Comment: @Ron Gordon :elliptic integral

Comment: @kingW3 : Yes , it's correct

Comment: Very complex elliptic integrals ! One tag is $\ definite-integrals$ : so, what are the bounds ?

Comment: Strange to write bizzare for bizarre and to use bizarre for standard.

Answer (score 3):

As the commenters said, **elliptic integral**.  For example,
$$
\int \!{\frac {dx}{\sqrt {9\,{x}^{4}+4\,{x}^{2}+1}}}=-\frac{\sqrt {-
2-i\sqrt {5}}}{3}\;{\rm F} \left( x\sqrt {-2+i\sqrt {5}},\sqrt 
\frac{-1+4\,i\sqrt {5}}{3} \right) 
$$
using the conventions of Maple, namely
$$
{\rm F} \left( z,k \right) :=\int _{0}^{z}\!{\frac {dt}{\sqrt {1-
{t}^{2}}\sqrt {1-{k}^{2}{t}^{2}}}}
$$